# 20.04: add/change order or world clock in command line

Tags: clock, gnome-clocks

I am using the World Clocks applet in Ubuntu 20.04 and would like to:

- change the order of the clocks without erase/re-add
- ideally set the clocks (order) from the command line

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, in theory.

You can get the currently selected locations with

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell.world-clocks locations
```

If you have specified, e.g., UTC and Amsterdam, this will give you

```
[<(uint32 2, <('Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)', '@UTC', false, @a(dd) [], @a(dd) [])>)>, <(uint32 2, <('Amsterdam', 'EHAM', true, [(0.91280719879303418, 0.083194033496160544)], [(0.91367986341903151, 0.085812027374152042)])>)>]
```

You can change the order of the blocks starting with `<(uint32` and write that string back to the `dconf` database using

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.world-clocks locations [string with modified clock order]
```

However, you will need to escape the parentheses and brackets in the new string to prevent the shell from interpreting them. I haven't managed to do do. Perhaps someone can chime in on how to fix the string.